# Failed to create instance of cookie value handler Error after SP 2013 SP1 Install

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation, service-pack

I have installed SP 2013 SP1 on my development server which has Windows Server 2012 R2 OS.

I have configured SP 2013 with Configuration Wizard.

After installing, Central Admin was created successfully.

Now I started to creata a site collection, and after I navigate to the url of the newly created site collection, am getting the dreaded

> Sorry something went wrong.
>   In the ULS log viewer, am able to see the below error description:

```
Unexpected  Failed to create instance of cookie value handler 
 type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSessionSecurityTokenCookieValue'.
```

Whenever I create a sub site or app (document library, list etc) or navigating to the Site pages library, I am getting the same `SecurityTokenCookieValue`  error.

I have received the below description from event viewer :

> Reason: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Technical Support Details: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException': Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 'System.InvalidOperationException': This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms. at 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor()' --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()' at 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean isAdministrationServiceJob)'

[image]

[image]
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: are you Using SSL?

Comment: No, am not using SSL.I just installed the SP1 and  started  seeing these   weird results. Also am going to update my question with more errors, hope Waqas can help troubleshoot and resolve.

Comment: couple of things you can do it...#1) try to remove and recreate the Distributed Cache. #2) restart the STS token services app pool.  at the end check the event log

Comment: I tried the STS thing as you mentioned.I stopped and restarted the same, i saw the similar issue and in social msdn forums and suggested msdn link which tells to restart the same.Also,I have deleted UPSA and created again, since i thought that user profiles may be corrupted. And in the healthreports section,the message says that,Security Token service not available.And its not issuing tokens.                                  Failing services: SPSecurityTokenService(SecurityTokenService)

Comment: I removed the DistributedCache through PowerShell and added again, but my site collection shows the same error. What should be done if the Security service is not issuing tokens?

Comment: check the event log on the server and see if you get any other clue?

Comment: also try this Add the following line into the aspnet.config on both FE machine.
<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>

Comment: can you pls tell where can I see aspnet.config file?   is the current web application's web.config you are referring to?

Comment: Mr.Waqas, Will update the results soon,as  am changing the aspnet.config from the Framework64\v4.0.30319 folder.

Comment: also check this one http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2013/09/sharepoint-installation-claims-error.html

Comment: Guru Waqas, the aspnet.config's entry  did the trick. <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false" /> and  perform IISRESET was the solution.  :-)  Thank you very much for your timely help.I have been going through this weird error for few days, now its solved! I am able to see the home page , add an app and access the settings page etc. without any issues!

Comment: I want to mark your comment as an answer , how to do that? I am unable to  see the tick mark for marking your comment - enablefipspolicy as answer.

Comment: Let me add this as answer and then you can mark it...

Comment: just did, please mark it answer...and i am sure iw ill get up vote as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things in this Scenrio, you can try to fix it.

1. repair the Distributed Cache on the server
2. Recycle the Security token service and app pool
3. Or, Add the following line into the aspnet.config on WebFrontend.`<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>`